# Trailhead Playground Users Blank

Tags: trailhead

I'm on `Trailhead Playground Management` > `Install Apps and Packages in Your Trailhead Playground`. When I went to look at `Setup > Administration > Users > Users`, the list of users wasn't there. the main content box was just white.

Similarly other settings on the setup was blank as well... Is there something I need to do first before entering the playground?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out this fix for myself. I was on Chrome and some of the cookies were being blocked, causing Salesforce to not load properly. I clicked on the cookie with the red x on the navbar and unblocked cookies from the playground as well as Salesforce in general. Then when I reloaded, the blank pages were populated.

Answer (score 0):

My new answer:

I think I've figured this one out. Sorry for the misunderstanding earlier. Here are the steps:

**Step 1:** Right click on the **Install the DreamHouse app package** link. Then click on **Copy link address**.

[image]

**Step 2:** Open a new tab in your broswer. Paste the link address.

[image]

**Step 3:** Go back to your trailhead module. Click on the **Launch** button to open your trailhead playground org.

[image]

**Step 4:** In your trailhead playground org, copy the first part of your url, aka My Domain.

[image]

**Step 5:** Go back to the tab that you've opened from Step 2. Replace the login.salesforce.com with your My Domain url. Press "enter" to proceed with installing your DreamHouse app.

[image]

Hope this helps you clear the trailhead module! =)

My old answer:

Salesforce has created a trailhead module on how to install apps and package onto your trailhead playground org. Did you have a chance to look into it?

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/trailhead_playground_management

Comment: That's actually the module I'm on! Literally says so in my question.

Comment: Which app/package are you trying to install? I'm trying to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Nvm I didn't read carefully. You're trying to install the DreamHouse app.

Comment: Apparently my issue was that Chrome was blocking Salesforce cookies, which made Salesforce render simply blank pages...